# Flash Builder (ecplise) syntax coloring not working

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

A few weeks ago syntax coloring stopped working for the odd file. Or halfway down a file. Now its becomming increasingly the norm.

I've cleaned the project, pruned out a whole heap of closed projects, but it hasnt improved things.

What would Stack Overflow suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this last week.  In my case my main application mxml file stopped having it's code highlighted.  Also I lost the ability to switch between source and code views for that file.  It was as if it was just being recognized as a basic text file.

To get it working again I had to create a new mxml file, made it the default application, copy/paste all my code over into the new file, delete the original file, and then rename my new mxml file to match the file I just deleted.  Then i went into my project properties and made sure my Run/Debug settings were still correct so i could launch/test the application again.

Comment: Yo I'll try this next time it occurs. Thanks

Comment: Fortunately for me, closing and reopoening Flash Builder (version 4.7 64Bit) solved this problem